# ClassNotFoundException: com.azure.storage.common.policy.RequestRetryOptions

Tags: java, azure

I am trying to run a java program that sends and receives messages to and from Azure Storage Queues; however, I keep getting the following ClassNotFoundException at runtime.  I am having a hard time finding the jars necessary to fix it.  Nothing I have found so far actually solves the problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/azure/storage/common/policy/RequestRetryOptions
        at com.azure.storage.queue.QueueServiceClientBuilder.<init>(QueueServiceClientBuilder.java:83)
        at com.cloudproject.azure.Connector.initiateConnection(Connector.java:58)
        at com.cloudproject.server.ConnectionServer.main(ConnectionServer.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.azure.storage.common.policy.RequestRetryOptions
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 3 more
```

I am not using maven in the build process, though I have pulled several jars from the maven repository - none of which have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed by including the azure-storage-common jar, which I pulled from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-common/12.1.0).  Not sure how I overlooked this one earlier.